# Scrolling fragment should collapse toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following program, in which I want to add a collapsing toolbar. It is a tab-layout, with multiple fragments attached.

**XML File**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabContentStart="72dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**JAVA File**

```
public class Competitions extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        setContentView(R.layout.competition);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Competitions");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new IntChal(), "International Challenges");
        adapter.addFragment(new XMach(), "Xtreme Machines");
        adapter.addFragment(new TVoltz(), "Technovoltz");
        adapter.addFragment(new Robotron(), "Robotron");
        adapter.addFragment(new Dimensions(), "Dimensions");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tinker(), "Tinkerer");
        adapter.addFragment(new Aero(), "Aerostrike");
        adapter.addFragment(new Lamp(), "Solar Urja Lamp");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I had tried this before, but when I replaced my toolbar with a collapsing toolbar, all that happened that it would collapse if I scroll the toolbar portion. What I require is that on scrolling the fragment down, the toolbar should collapse. How do I do that.

P.S. I am a beginner , so please explain why your solution works.

**EDIT**
Okay, what I want is that when I scroll the fragment, the toolbar should collapse on it's own. With the following solutions, what is happening is that I have to manually first collapse the toolbar , and then scroll through the fragment, which is not what I want. Please help me do the same

Comment: just add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to your `Toolbar` and `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `CoordinatorLayout` in XML

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `Scrolling Activity` project in android studio. Which gives you a `collapsing toolbar`. Steps: Android studio -> Add New Project -> Give project details -> in step `Add an activity to mobile` select `Scrolling Activity` . Done

[image: Steps for adding Scrolling activity]

Answer (score 0):

Change your toolbar like this

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"            
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

See example here at 'https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare' for more reference, it is working fine for me. i hope it can help you.

Answer (score -1):

seem your layout is correct, refer this [tutorial](https://github.com/Aspsine/SwipeToLoadLayout) it will help you to achieve your goal.

**Update:**

Adding   `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to toolbar will resolve your issue.